# Loading Content dynamically into a regular webpage or jQuery mobile ?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I have a question.

I don't have much experience in programming. I am willing to learn quickly, but I want to make sure I am going in the right direction.

I am looking to build a jQuery mobile application that updates content automatically. Speaking of, I create the applcation with plain jquery mobile  html5 thenI want to modify some text, or change a picture every now and then?

What's the best way to do that and what do I need to learn ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web development basics:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript
- jQuery
- jQuery Mobile

You'll also want to use a programming language such as PHP (or any other language and web framework, but this is an easy place to start for a beginner).  You can use PHP to generate your dynamic content by talking to a database or other content source.

Comment: Also, consider taking courses at a site like Codecamy that teaches web development basics: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web